# Optimizing cypher query (self-join)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have the below self-join query.In my test environment, Label `BASE` has around 21600 nodes and it is slow. How can I optimize it for bigger data like 1 billion nodes?

```
MATCH (a:BASE) 
MATCH (b:BASE {TICKET_ID: a.TICKET_ID})
CREATE (:CALC { X_PRODUCT_ID: a.PRODUCT_ID, X_PRODUCT_DESC: a.PRODUCT_DESC, Y_PRODUCT_ID: b.PRODUCT_ID, Y_PRODUCT_DESC:b.PRODUCT_DESC,  
         X_KPI_UNITS:a.KPI_UNITS,  Y_KPI_UNITS:b.KPI_UNITS, X_KPI_SALES:a.KPI_SALES,  Y_KPI_SALES:b.KPI_SALES, X_PROMO_FLAG:a.PROMO_FLAG, 
         Y_PROMO_FLAG:b.PROMO_FLAG})
```

I created the following index for this query:

```
 create index ON :BASE(TICKET_ID);
```

Comment: So with this query you are creating 21600 new nodes, that is one factor for the execution time. And is there no relation between a:BASE and b:BASE?

Comment: In the first line, you match all `BASE` nodes. Do you really have to create nodes for the cross product of all `BASE` nodes? What is the logic behind this and the query you want to run afterwards?

Comment: @Remco no I do not have relationship. Can I make a relationship to node itself? then I can match the relationship just and put the values to CALC. right?

Comment: @MartinPreusse I want to duplicate values of BASE that have the same ticket_id to create two dimensions in CALC label. I want to know what relationships do I need for this query to make it faster?